# how to create a collection in mongodb and specify the data type for the fields

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am new to nosql i want to create a collection in mongodb .When i saw the tutorials all are teaching about inserting. i am wondering whether we could create a collection with specific data type. example when we create a table in sql we will give the specific data type for that so can we create a collection like that in nosql?

example (SQL)

```
create table test(
id primary key auto increment,
date_en date
number int);
```

please help me with this

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Actually  **MongoDB** is a **schemaless** database because of MongoDB is a JSON-style data store. The documents stored in the database can have varying sets of fields, with different types for each field.

But it doesn’t mean that there is no way to define schema. You can define schema as you need for your project. You can use some tools to define your schema like **mongoose**.

Here I am showing the process of defining schema using mongoose.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var mySchema= new Schema({
  title:  String,
  date_en: Date,
  number: Number
}); 
module.exports = mongoose.model('collectionname', mySchema);
```

OR

```
var mySchema= new Schema({
  title:  { type: String},
  date_en: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  number: {type: Number}
}); 

 module.exports = mongoose.model('collectionname', mySchema);
```

**N.B:** according to your collection name will do create table name and mongoose will create `_id` **automatically** and **unique** also so no need to define for `id`

For more information can visit [Mongoose site](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is not possible in mongo db to define schemas.
Please refer to this link from mongo's official documentation.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/

*"Data in MongoDB has a flexible schema. Unlike SQL databases, where you must determine and declare a table’s schema before inserting data, MongoDB’s collections do not enforce document structure. This flexibility facilitates the mapping of documents to an entity or an object. Each document can match the data fields of the represented entity, even if the data has substantial variation. In practice, however, the documents in a collection share a similar structure."*